# Ubuntu 22.04 RDP remote desktop screen update lag

Tags: gnome, remote-desktop, 22.04, rdp

The new RDP connection is amazing. I have got an issue though where the screen doesn't update quickly when I do things like right click to open some menu or sometimes even typing/using backspace in the terminal.

A workaround that I've found is that if I move the cursor after doing an action, it forces screen updates but this is very annoying to have to do.

I'm using the default Ubuntu 22.04 RDP screen sharing and accessing it with both windows and Android Microsoft RDP clients elicits the same behaviour.

Is this the intended behaviour for RDP or is there a setting I can tweak to improve this?

Thanks

Comment: can you be sure its the 22.04 RDP client and not the remote device which causes the delay? For example, have you tried (say) a 20.04 RDP client to 22.04 and vice versa for test purposes?

Comment: Just tried with Remmina on my Ubuntu laptop. The same lag issue exists with Remmina as well

Answer (score 2):

ubuntu 22.04 - recently ran into this issue Typing in terminal does not update unless the mouse is moved.
Fine using a VM on a windows host but using a real machine on the lan it is very bad.
Solution was to switch to "Ubuntu on Xorg" at the login options.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm however limited to using Wayland as I'm running Android apps on Waydroid

Answer (score 1):

The symptoms that you describe and especially the workaround ("if I move the cursor after doing an action, it forces screen updates") sound very like https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/2282 (mutter issue).

It is fixed by https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/commit/9fba0fbb7c272cc432d60a1e6e5d035446c4992f and the commit is in the mutter-42.3 release.

Currently, Ubuntus mutter version in 22.04 is still at 42.2 (Ubuntus SRU team often take a lot of time to push the updates).
So it is basically a matter of time, until Ubuntu pushes the update to its users.

Comment: Waiting for the update to check it