# ms-rd stop responding in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: remote-desktop

I set up ms-rd (RDP) screen sharing on my Ubuntu 22.04 machine.
I disabled key storage via setting password as ''(no input and make "ok")
and activated auto-login

But, I can connect via RDP for first a hour, and then I can't connect to Ubuntu via RDP.
SSH works well, and machine is running well but only RDP doesn't work.
(Just displaying "Initiating Remote Session"

Also I'm experiencing Keyboard Input lag on RDP
Clicking something is OK but typing anything including English and Korean language makes delay on remote control.

Fully updated machine via sudo apt update and upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the typing lag, see https://askubuntu.com/a/1422857/1621950. Both descriptions sound very similar.

Regarding "I can connect via RDP for first a hour, and then I can't connect to Ubuntu via RDP":

The symptom description sound like, that the lock screen may have appeared on the server side.
As described in https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Mutter/RemoteDesktop, gnome-remote-desktop currently only implements a "Remote Assistance" mode.

Headless session are currently not implemented, but in the works.
See also https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-remote-desktop/-/issues/16 for this

In the mean time, you can use the "Allow Locked Remote Desktop" extension, which overrides the calls in gnome-shell to disconnect all remote desktop sessions with noop calls: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4338/allow-locked-remote-desktop/

Comment: thanks for tip, will wait ubuntu update!

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04:

At login screen in bottom right corner press the little gear icon, and select Ubuntu on Xorg instead of just Ubuntu ( i think Wayland window manager is used there by default ).

Useful link: https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland/

Thanks to [Игор](https://askubuntu.com/users/51624/%D0%98%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80) for answer